# I need to add a clause to an existing trigger (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

Just learning to script triggers. The existing trigger is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T_FSITEMS_I] 
ON [dbo].[FSItems] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
   IF UPDATE (Condition)
       UPDATE FSItems 
       SET ... 
       WHERE ... 

   UPDATE FSItems_A
   SET ... 
   FROM ..., inserted 
   WHERE ... = inserted.IDItem AND ...=inserted.IDItem
```

I interpret this to mean:

1. here is a trigger for both insert & update.
2. if the condition column is being updated, do something (`update FSItems_A`)
3. then no matter what, do something (`update FSItems_A`)

So if I want to add another unconditional update, do I simply but it at the end? I'm a little leery because I don't see any BEGIN-END block delimiters.

So if I just put

```
UPDATE FSItems 
SET artistlname = LEFT(inserted.title,64) 
FROM FSItems, inserted 
WHERE FSItems.IDItem = inserted.IDItem AND inserted.type  = 0
```

following everything above, will this simply extend the trigger, completely independently of any prior logic?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @user1693404 , one more thing to add IF UPDATE (), works on both update and insert.